# Mother Board Issue

Tags: motherboard

I am attempting to repair a computer and getting no where. When the computer was turned on the monitor was not getting a signal. Then i switched monitors hoping it was a bad monitor or cable, nothing still. So i switched from video card to onboard video card with no success. I then unplugged the expanded video card and cleared the motherboard bios with the jumper. Tried again with the on board video card with (expanded video card removed still) no success. At this point im thinking its the motherboard. So i unplugged all the perpetuals and the motherboard acted the same it has. Keep in mind, i have no working video so i cant tell if its going through the post screen. after removing all the perpetuals, i removed the CPU and attempted the get the motherboard speaker to beep at me. Nothing, the mother board acted just like it has all night.

My question is, with out a motherboard speaker and no working video, how do i test to see if the motherboard has failed?

Comment: If you computer is able to create POST beeps you can refer to this [website](http://www.computerhope.com/beep.htm) to understand what they mean

Answer (score 0):

Grab a POST card, stick it in a slot, and power the machine on. The exact set of codes varies by BIOS manufacturer and will be available on the POST card manufacturer's website.

Comment: That would defiantly get me an answer but i don't have one of those. Any other ways i can test it tonight? thanks for suggesting that, i will be picking one up soon!